# The associated partition function generates more partitions than there are file groups mentioned in the scheme

Tags: sql, partitioning

I am trying to create a partition to hold data older than the current year in a ARCHIVE file.

However I get the following error:

> The associated partition function 'pfnYears' generates more partitions than there are file groups mentioned in the scheme 'pscYears'.

code:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRO_DW Add Filegroup [CURRO_DW_ARCHIVE]

Alter Database CURRO_DW Add FILE ( NAME = N'CURRO_DW_ARCHIVE', FILENAME = N'D:\Data\CURRO_DW_ARCHIVE.ndf' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO Filegroup [CURRO_DW_ARCHIVE]`

DROP PARTITION SCHEME pscYears

DROP PARTITION FUNCTION pfnYears

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pfnYears (INT)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES 
(
2017,2020
) 

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME pscYears AS PARTITION pfnYears
TO
(
[CURRO_DW_ARCHIVE],[PRIMARY]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With two boundaries you need 3 filegroups because the data is split in 3 segments:
< 2017
between 2017 and 2020
`> 2020